# How can I convert two fields in a dataframe into a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn

My question is based on Affinity Propagation from the scikit learn library.  I found some sample code from the link below, and it runs fine, as-is.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html

I am trying to modify the code to do the same for my own specific dataset.  From the sample code in the link above, an array of prices is generated to look like this.

```
array([[ 14.8 ,  14.9 ,  14.9 , ..., 198.57, 199.83, 198.08],
       [ 60.3 ,  60.12,  62.14, ...,  58.01,  57.94,  58.3 ],
       [ 19.57,  20.52,  20.7 , ...,  94.25,  94.45,  92.64],
       ...,
       [ 35.47,  35.5 ,  36.38, ...,  93.67,  95.  ,  93.69],
       [  8.16,   8.28,   8.44, ...,  16.19,  16.34,  16.19],
       [ 17.6 ,  18.1 ,  18.94, ...,  23.71,  23.45,  23.26]])
```

If I check variation.shape, I see this:  `(56, 1258)`

Then, a model is applied, fit, and labels are generated.  That all works fine.

However, when I try to modify the code and feed in my own specific dataset, I seeing some issues.

```
# Learn a graphical structure from the correlations
edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV()

# standardize the time series: using correlations rather than covariance
# is more efficient for structure recovery
X = variation.copy().T
X /= X.std(axis=0)
edge_model.fit(X)

# Cluster using affinity propagation

_, labels = cluster.affinity_propagation(edge_model.covariance_)
n_labels = labels.max()

for i in range(n_labels + 1):
    print('Cluster %i: %s' % ((i + 1), ', '.join(names[labels == i])))
```

In my case, I am trying to grab two fields from a dataframe, and feed it into the model, in the form of an array:

```
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(returns['Price']),np.asarray(returns['PriceChange'])]).T

# Learn a graphical structure from the correlations
edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV()

# standardize the time series: using correlations rather than covariance
# is more efficient for structure recovery
X = variation.copy().T
X /= X.std(axis=0)
edge_model.fit(X)

# Cluster using affinity propagation

_, labels = cluster.affinity_propagation(edge_model.covariance_)
n_labels = labels.max()

for i in range(n_labels + 1):
    print('Cluster %i: %s' % ((i + 1), ', '.join(names[labels == i])))
```

I try to run that code, and this line:  `edge_model.fit(X)`

Throws this error:

`ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=2.`

variation.shape gives me this: `(17379, 2)`

I think that's the problem.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: looks like when you apply `X = variation.copy().T` the shape changes to `(2,17379)` and the samples size become 2 which why you get error,try avoiding `.T`

Comment: That may have actually worked.  Now, I'm down to the end; at the for-loop.  I'm seeing this error.  IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 17379 but corresponding boolean dimension is 17.  There are 17379 rows in the data set and 17 labels.  This must be close, but I'm still missing something here.

Comment: what is `names[labels == i]` is doing?

Comment: That part loops through all the labels that are created (labels are Cluster IDs) in the step above.  It is also mapping labels to names, so you can see which names are associated with which labels (Clusters).  That's what it is supposed to do.  It doesn't work though.

Comment: so, `names=['label_name1',label_name2',...]` and `labels=[3,2,8...]` and you want to print out names assoicated with each labels correct?  if that so why don't just use `names[labels[i]]`

Comment: Oh, nice.  I didn't think of that.  I'll try that now.  Thanks!!